# Hand sign symbols

Tags: symbols, packages, icon

`LaTeX` has shown me to be of great advantage over any text editor for writing long works, specially when require:

- writing equations,
- automatic numbering (chapters, sections, pages, equations, citations, references, etc), and
- diagram design (tikz, circuitikz, chemfig, chessboard).

I would like to highlight here how easy it is to write lessons on chess using `chessfss`, `xskak`, and `chessboard` packages.

Having this in mind, my question is: is there any package to display hand configurations like in sign languages for deafs? (For example, to display the letters of alphabet, as in figure below.)

[image]

Comment: includegraphics?

Comment: Includegraphics only adds figure. I specifficaly would like to have icons just like I can add chess pieces in the text. I don't know if I am clear. The aim is not to keep adding png, jpg, etc, images. I would like to have hands as text characters.

Comment: http://luc.devroye.org/sign.html should be of interest if you compile with `luatex` or `xetex`.

Comment: `\includegraphics` can be used whereever a letter can be used, and if you use (eg} `[height=1ex]` it will be the same size as a  letter.  It is unrelated to the `figure` environment.

Comment: You are right @DavidCarlisle. But the problem I rise is that I don't have the images for all hands configurations. And it is hard to browse them and crop in order to get image and border sizes good to print inside text. Built in icons via packages would be grat and that's what I am looking for.

Comment: There are many sign language fonts available.  For example:  https://www.dafont.com/american-sign-language.font   You can use these directly with the tex engines that support OTF (xelatex and lualatex etc)

Comment: That's amazing, @Thruston. How to use it in LaTeX? I'm afraid only the alphabet is avalable, but not other hand signs.

Comment: Just install the font like any other system font and read the [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec?lang=en) documentation, particularly the section on "Commands to select single font faces".